# Diretório Publico - Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, express.js, multer

**Diretório Publico Node.js**

Estou tendo problemas ao liberar um diretório publico no Node.js.
Eu preciso que tudo que estiver no diretório *public* seja acessível via URL direto.

Já tentei usar `app.use(express.static('public'));` porem sem sucesso.

Estou usando estas dependências:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mssql": "^4.1.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.1"
  }
```

O arquivo deveria ser acessado por alguma URL parecido com:

- http://localhost:3020/consultaavancada/public/uploads/nfd/1550581279905_boleto.pdf
- http://localhost:3020/consultaavancada/uploads/nfd/1550581279905_boleto.pdf

Ou o node não tem este suporte?

***EDIT 1: Adicionando imagens.***

**Index.js**:

[image: Código fonte Node.js]

**Diretório:**
[image: Diretório]

**Tentativa 1**
[image: Tentativa1]

**Tentativa 2**
[image: Tentativa2]

**Estrutura de Pasta:**

[image: Pastas]

**Rota:**

[image: Rota]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez o `Node` não esteja procurando no diretório correto quando você cria o `endpoint`. Altere para o seguinte:

```
const path = require('path');

// ...

application.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

E assim acessar:

> ```
> /public/uploads/nfd/1550581279905_boleto.pdf
> ```

Ou:

```
const path = require('path');

// ...

application.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

E assim acessar:

> ```
> /public/uploads/nfd/1550581279905_boleto.pdf
> ```

Ou ainda:

```
const path = require('path');

// ...

application.use(express.static('/consultaavancada', path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

E assim acessar:

> ```
> /consultaavancada/uploads/nfd/1550581279905_boleto.pdf
> ```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. Mas eu testei das duas formas e não funcionou. Pelo que eu vi na internet isso funcionaria para caso eu queira importar arquivos js, css ou img para página em questão. Mas o que eu quero mesmo é que eu possa acessar esse PDF direto pelo link, fora do site.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para acrescentar imagens, vê se ajuda melhor assim... Qualquer coisa coloco mais informação se precisar.

Comment: Adicionei a estrutura de pastas e as rotas

Comment: @PedroDaher fora que sua URL parece estar errada. Faça a chamada sem o `consultaavancada`: `http://localhost:3020/public/uploads/nfd/1550581279905_boleto.pdf`

Comment: Fiz a chamada sem o `consultaavancada` e também não foi, mas acho que devo manter ele, pois na rota ele está configurado.

Comment: @PedroDaher Tentou dos dois jeitos sem o `consultaavancada`?

Comment: Testei sim, eu fiz um teste adicionei o `consultaavancada` no trecho do código que você postou ali em cima, ficando `app.use('/consultaavancada/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` e funcionou. Você me salvou man!! Muito obrigado.